# Trim and fill funnel plot on a single proportion meta analysis

Tags: r, meta-analysis, excel, funnel-plot

I have performed a single proportion meta analysis with R. The package I used can perform a trim and fill analysis, but can't actually plot the trim and fill funnel plot. The packages that can do so, can't perform a single proportion meta analysis. How can a create these trim and fill plots?
[image]

[image]

Comment: What software are you trying to use? In Stata, you can use metafunnel. In R you can use the metafor package. In Excel, you must build it manually which would require reading up on how the two diagonal lines are calculated.

Comment: Since it is tagged R I assume that is your preferred software. Take a look at the CRAN Task View on MetaAnalysis https://CRAN.R-project.org/view=MetaAnalysis where you will find lots of options. (Disclaimer: I maintain the CTV).

Comment: @dbwilson I have managed to plot the 2 funnel plots and was able to get the Numbers on the trim and fill calculations. The problem I now have is that I am not able to get these trim and fill plots. I have looked on the CRAN website and over the internet But wasnt able to find a solution. Do you perhaps know how I can plot them?

Comment: The Task view mentions three packages which perform funnel plots and two of them are stated to also do trim and fill so that would be the next place to look to see if their funnel plots deal with trim and fill.

Comment: @dbwilson the problem is that I used the only package that could perform a single proportion meta analysis. That package couldn't create a trim and fill plot. The other packages that can create the trim and fill funnel plot can't perform the single proportion meta analysis. Are there any other options?

Comment: This is really getting off-topic here as a request for help with R code. Is there any particular reason why you have rejected the metafor package?

Comment: Because I wasn't able to pool the single proportion data with the metaphor package.

Comment: @dbwilson therefor I've used the metaprop package

Comment: To do this you just need to calculate your own effect size and variance. In this case it is the logit. Mteafor can work with any effect size and it's variance or standard error.

Comment: Just to add to @dbwilson comment the metafor web site has a section on this very topic http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses and look for the section on proportions.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. Using the meta package, it is not clearly stated how to plot the trim and fill funnel plot. But dr. Schwarzer gave me the answer.

Library(meta)

#
Data examples from Newcombe (1998)

#

event<-c(81,15,0,1)

n<-c(263,148,20,29)

#

m1<-metaprop(event,n)

funnel(trimfill(m1))